# listing possible outcomes for 3 items with 3 possible outcome for each item using php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have been trying to write a function in php that will output all possible outcome. Unfortunately I keep hitting a brick wall. So I was hoping someone could help me. Here is what I am trying to get
there are 3 items with 3 possible outcomes. So there would be

`(A <-> B) with x,y,z possible outcome`

`(C <-> D) with x,y,z possible outcome`

`(E <-> F) with x,y,z possible outcome`

I am trying to write a script that will give me all the possible outcomes for all of them without repeating such that I would get

`(A <-> B)  (C <-> D)  (C <-> D)`

```
`x           x          x`
`y           x          x`
`z           x          x`
`y           y          y`
`z           y          y`
`z           y          y`
`z           z          z`
```

and so on for each item ...

any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: What output you need?

Comment: just need the outputs like in the example, I hope I am making sense. Basically all all possible combinations xyz

Comment: What is A, B, C and D why combine only XYZ

Comment: I am just using the letters as an example, i think I might have found what I am looking for [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506677/2-independent-events-3-times-enumerate-the-possible-outcomes?rq=1)

Comment: Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022215/php-how-do-you-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-values-in-an-array